# Jumping to the method which executes when a Jbutton is clicked while debugging through Intellij

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

I am using an application which has a huge code base and uses Java Swings for GUI creation. Now I want to know the method or the part of code which gets triggered when i click on a specific JButton while I am in Debug mode in Intellij. Is there a work around for this situation?

Comment: do you really think that if you debug your code, clicking a JButton will trigger another method than just running it would? check the actionPerformed method of your ActionListener

Comment: Thing is I am new to Java and the code base is too huge and I don't know where the ActionListener of that jButton has been Implemented. I was just thinking if there is a way that automatically adds a breakpoint to the corresponding actionPerformed method of that JButton.

Comment: look into the code where you see: addActionListener(...) that should tell you where to find it

Comment: There is no way to automatically add a breakpoint in that actionPerformed. (not that I've ever seen)

Comment: You need to find the JButton in your code base first, and then find its action handler. If the JButton has text you can use that as a starting point for searching through the large code base to locate the button's associated code.

Comment: That JButton does have a toolTipText. How can I use that text to reach that button's declaration?

Comment: search for that text in your code, or where it is used. how new are you to java?

Comment: I have used intellij for a while now and I know I can search files, modules and variables in the entire project given that i know their names but I don't think i can search a String(Tool tip text) in the entire project.

Comment: You can search for just about anything in IntelliJ. You dont need to provide it the full Java code that sets the tooltip, just the text displayed in the tooltip popup. That should be enough to locate the source code (assuming it's part of your project and not a 3rd party library).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IntelliJ, right-click the top most element in your project and select **Find in Path** and then type in the tooltip text (or other unique identifying text for that button). This should hopefully locate the source code where the button is defined, and then you can locate where the `addActionListener` method is called for your button. This only works if your source code contains the button code (i.e. it's not included via a 3rd party library).

Alternatively, you can try looking at the class hierarchy of the `ActionListener` to locate the listener for your button (open the class in IntelliJ and select **Navigate** > **Type Hierarchy**, or Ctrl+H is the default keybaord shortcut). This will list *all* implementations in your app so it will likely be a very large list:

[image]

Lastly, you should be able to set a break point on `ActionListener.actionPerformed` in IntelliJ. Then debug your app and click your button, and it should take you to the action listener.

[image]